# mysql | conditional price request

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have a conditional request from my database but it seems not work as expected.
I would like to fetch minimal/maximal price if current datetime between action boundaries and regular price if it's not in.

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN NOW() BETWEEN `from` AND `to` THEN MAX(action_price) ELSE MAX(price) END AS max,
    CASE WHEN NOW() BETWEEN `from` AND `to` THEN MIN(action_price) ELSE MIN(price) END AS min
FROM 
    `prices`
```

My fields "from" and "to" are DATETYPE in mysql;
Where is my mistake?
Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps `CASE WHEN curdate() between`

Comment: what's the problem with the current query? what is its output and where is it wrong?